# I have a mean and a desired range for a normal distribution, how do I discover what standard deviation I need?

Tags: normal-distribution, average, standard-deviation

I have a mean and a desired range for a normal distribution, how do I discover what standard deviation I need?  I may not be using the correct terminology so here's a graph:

[image]

Based on this, if you have a mean of 0 and range that's about -1.5 to 1.5 the graph shows you need to use a standard deviation the square root of 0.2 (the blue line).

Here's some examples of the problems I'm trying to solve:

1. If my mean is 100 and I want the range to be from 90 to 110, how do I figure out what standard deviation I need?
2. If my mean is 50 and I want the range to be from 0 to 100, how do I figure out what standard deviation I need?

Comment: I *think* I figured this out on my own.  Wikipedia says that 100% of the graph will be under 3 standard deviations.  Therefore, I just need to take the upper range, divide by 3 and that becomes my standard deviation.  Let me know if that's wrong, thanks.

Comment: Correction above: "about 99.7% are within three standard deviations"

Answer (score 2):

To be completely precise, the normal distribution has an infinite range - because no matter how high you go, there's still some probability of going higher.

In practice, your question makes perfect sense - truly normal distributions don't go beyond, say, 10 standard deviations more than once every supercalifragilisticatillion times.

Normally (pardon the pun) you'll define something like a "confidence interval" - so if you say "X is between a and b" you'll only be wrong 5% of the time, or 1% or so on. The probability $\alpha$ you choose defines a "critical value" $z_{\alpha/2}$ - so, if you want to be wrong only 5% of the time, your critical value will be 1.96, because $z_{0.025}=1.96$.

Then, you can work out your interval from your mean and standard deviation:

$\mu\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sigma$

If you already have an interval, say $(a,b)$, you just let $a=\mu-z_{\alpha/2}\sigma$ and $b=\mu+z_{\alpha/2}\sigma$ and solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma$. This will give

$\mu=\frac{a+b}2$

and

$\sigma=\frac{b-a}{2z_{\alpha/2}}$

Comment: Hm, that's way different than what I came up with (see my comment on my question).  Is my solution a specific solution and yours a general solution, or am I way off?

Comment: You used the informal idea that a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is "always" between $\mu-3\sigma$ and $\mu+3\sigma$. This is not strictly speaking true, it is between these two values with probability about $0.993$.

Comment: ... and it is between $\mu - 10 \sigma$ and $\mu + 10 \sigma$ with probability about $1 - 1.52 \times 10^{-23}$.

Comment: so it's outside that range about $15$ times in every septillion.

Comment: If each of the approximately $7$ billion people on earth generated an independent normally distributed random variable once a second (and the population stayed constant), the expected time until one of those random variables was more than $10$ standard deviations from the mean would be about $300,000$ years.